# Error with self invoking functions in python code

Tags: python, function

When I call the mainfile, the below mention validate functions do not execute as expected. What changes shall I make with the mainfile so that the validate methods execute themselves?

```
x = input('enter a number')

def mainfile(data):
  def validate(self,data):
    if int(data) > 3:
     print( 'greater than 3')
  def validate1(self, data):
    if int(data) > 2:
      print( 'greater than 2')

mainfile(x);
```

Comment: You even didn't call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only **defining** `validate`, you arne't **calling** it:

```py
def mainfile(data):
  def validate(self,data):
    if int(data) > 3:
     print( 'greater than 3')
  def validate1(self, data):
    if int(data) > 2:
      print( 'greater than 2')

  # You could, e.g., call them here:
  validate(data)
  validate1(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly those methods don't belong to a class, so the self keyword is not needed here and must be removed to avoid a Type error due to missing positional arguments.

Secondly, you don't call the nested functions validate and validate1, so hence they are never executed. You must directly call them from the mainfile function. E.g. `validate(data)` `validate1(data)`

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the functions validate and validate1, but they are not called if you only use the function mainfile. Also, you only need the keyword 'self' in the context of classes, so you can just leave it out here.